# SMT proximity sensor

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

I'm using a touch LCD whose content I want to change if the user moves toward it. For this I'm looking for an SMT proximity sensor with a 40~50 cm detection range. Space above the PCB is only 3 mm, so Sharp GP2D12 and the like are out.

*note* - I'm not looking for shopping advice ("where can I buy part xyz?"), but rather design advice ("How can I solve this design problem?")

Comment: Answerers: Please be aware that this could be a [bad shopping question](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping).  Please remember to include how you found the proximity sensor, so that Federico and other readers can find sensors applicable to their situation in the future.

Comment: If you could edit your question to better conform to the FAQ, you'd learn more, get better answers, and get more votes.  Please read the first section of the  [FAQ](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq) and peruse the [[shopping](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping)] tag on Meta to learn about our policy on shopping questions.

Comment: @reemrevnivek - I agree with Federico that this isn't a shopping question. There are lots of questions which have answers like "You could use a ...". Wouldn't that also be shopping advice then?

Comment: @reemrevnivek: I read the first section of the FAQ, and it says questions about "a specific electronics design problem" are OK. Doesn't this apply to my question?

Comment: Your previous question was borderline, but the revised version is just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mouser's latest mailing mentioned this one: [Vishay VCNL4000](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83798/vcnl4000.pdf). For the price of the proximity sensor you also get an ambient light sensor. 4mm x 4mm, 0.75mm high, though it has three blobs on it which make it somewhat higher. Still looks like it's less than 3mm.

[image]

Detection range for the proximity sensor is only 20cm, though.

*disclaimer: the mention of Mouser is not a shopping advice :-)*